# Yii CActiveDataProvider not sorting properly

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to query 4 tables in YII1 and after getting results i am trying to group them and then sorting. but sorting is not working properly.

here is my code

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = 't.log_id,t.message, t.date_added';

        $criteria->with = array(
            'camp' => array(
                'select'   => 'camp.name',
                'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
                'together' => true,
                'customer' => array(
                        'select'    => 'cus.id, customer.name,
                        'joinType'  => 'INNER JOIN',
                        'together'  => true,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'driver' => array(
                'select'    => 'driver.name',
                'joinType'  => 'INNER JOIN',
                'together'  => true,
            ),
        );

        $criteria->addCondition('t.message=\'OK\'');
        $criteria->addInCondition('camp.status', array('done', 'processing', 'pending'));

        //i have also use this on this place
        //$criteria->order = 't.date_added DESC';

        //i have also use this on this place
        //$criteria->order = 't.log_id DESC';

        $criteria->group = 't.camp_id,driver.driver_id';
        $criteria->order = 't.date_added DESC';

        //i have also use this on this
        //$criteria->order = 't.log_id DESC';

        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('modelname', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));

         $dataArray=$dataProvider->getData();

       foreach($dataArray as $item1)
       {
        echo $item1->log_id."<br>";
       }
```

now when i run this application first time i got this output

```
1242206
1235814
1234853
```

its look like my table last log_id is 1242206 but my table last is

```
1243104
```

with all conditions same, it just don't sort.

Thanks for help.